# Process user input to "phrase/3" method in Prolog

Tags: prolog, swi-prolog, dcg

I have build a DCG with Prolog. The code works, when I do the following call:

```
phrase(programm(R), [1,+,2], []).
```

I want the user to write the input, so I did this:

```
main :- read(Input), atom_chars(Input, R), write(R), phrase(programm(E), R).
```

Calling main and input e.g. '1+2' doesn't work. How can I process the user input to the phrase method for calling my DCG?

Comment: If `phrase(programm(R), [1,+,2], [])` is what works when you run it on its own, why not use, `phrase(programm(E), R, [])` in your `main` predicate?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SWI-Prolog offers an handy way, by means of [tokenize_atom](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=tokenize_atom/2).

```
program(sum(L,R)) --> [L, +, R].

?- tokenize_atom('1 + 2', L), phrase(program(P), L).
L = [1, +, 2],
P = sum(1, 2).
```

Answer (score 3):

The fundamental problem is the way you have defined characters and numbers in your grammar.  I assume you defined something along:

```
program(sum(L,R)) -->
    [L],
    [+],
    [R].
```

You need first

```
:- set_prolog_flag(double_quotes, chars).

program(sum(L,R)) -->
   number(L),
   "+",
   number(R).

number(1) --> "1".
```

Note that `1` is an integer and `"1"` is `['1']`!